# Move Files with S3BotoStorage

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3, django-storage

I'm using [S3BotoStorage](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) from [django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages) to handle my media and static files on my S3 Bucket for my Django backend.

Everything works as expected, but the backend raises a not ImplementedError because it is not a local filesystem when I call self.image.path on a where Image is a models.Image Field. This is [expected behavior](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.path).

However I'm using the path to move the image with os.rename (which wouldnt work on my bucket as well). What would be the approach to move that file on the bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `os` to move your file, you should use the [storage](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#storage)

To move your file, you can use the `read()` method on your `FileField` (or in this case, `ImageField`), (and eventually use the `storage` to delete the old file).

```
file_content = my_model.my_image.read()
file_name = my_model.my_image.name

# Renaming the file
my_model.my_image = my_model.my_image.save('new_file_name', ContentFile(file_content))

# If you want to delete the original file afterwards:
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
default_storage.delete(file_name)
```

Comment: This is probably a very computing intensive operation for larger files like images right?